# What is meant by "compute it modulo 1,000,000,007"?

Tags: c, modulo, calculation

I am doing a contest problem. Attaching an excerpt here -

*Find the maximum profit Chef can make if he sells his cars in an optimal way. Since this number may be large, compute it modulo 1,000,000,007 (10^9+7).*

Does this simply mean I have to find the remainder of the final profit on dividing by 1000000007? Pardon me for this simple question, the language is not clear.

Comment: yes and make sure you know the modular operation rules.

Comment: This does raise the question whether you should compute `(max(profits))%mod` or `max(profits%mod)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the context of this remark, *10^9+7* is meant to be read as *10<sup>9</sup>+7*, which is `1000000007`.

Very large numbers will exceed the range of integer types, so you are asked to compute the result modulo 1000000007 (ie: compute the remainder of the division by 1000000007), which can be achieved by reducing the intermediary results modulo 1000000007 whenever they exceed or equal this value, as long as the final result is obtained by additions and multiplications. [Modular Arithmetics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) has many more interesting properties. Pupils are told a simple way to check arithmetic operations, computing modulo `9` by adding the digits.

For example, you can compute factorials modulo 1000000007 this way:

```
long factorial_mod(int n) {
    long res = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        res = res * (long long)i % 1000000007;
    }
    return res;
}
```